# K8S How to add quotes when on parameters provided for `kubectl exec -c`

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

I am using K8S

I want to calculate a string that that is a result of `kubectl exec -it ... -c`

after the `-c` option there is a string.

How can I pass a string with double quotes inside.

The following example doesn't work properly.

```
x="$(kubectl exec -it mysql-pod -- /bin/sh -c \"mysql -uroot -p12345
   -e 'show databases'\" 2>/dev/null)"
echo $x
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you `kubectl port-forward` to the pod, then run the `mysql` client locally?  That would avoid multiple layers of quoting and escaping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- when only a command needs to be executed on a pod , `-it` option is not required as it stands for attaching an interactive teminal
- when mysql is itself an executable command , no need to use `/bin/sh -c`
- no need to encapsulate whole command in `" "`

So try following

```
x=$(kubectl exec mysql-pod -- mysql -uroot -p12345 -e 'show databases ;' 2>/dev/null)
echo $x
```

Comment: Yes, hreat. It works. BTW - if I need to add an aprostphe - how could I do that? i.e password with @ or any speciail character? I also may meed some command line to calculate that password

Comment: you can add single quotes to password without any changes to whole command , it should work fine , x=$(kubectl exec mysql-pod -- mysql -uroot -p'12345' -e 'show databases ;' 2>/dev/null)